# Are on-line backpropagation iterations perpendicular to the constraint?

Tags: backpropagation, math, gradient-descent

[Raul Rojas' Neural Networks A Systematic Introduction, section 8.1.2](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K8.pdf#page=9) relates off-line backpropagation and on-line backpropagation with Gauss-Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods for finding the intersection of two lines.

What I can't understand is how the iterations of on-line backpropagation are perpendicular to the (current) constraint. More specifically, how is $\frac12(x_1w_1 + x_2w_2 - y)^2$'s gradient, $(x_1,x_2)$, normal to the constraint $x_1w_1 + x_2w_2 = y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by [Theo Bandit](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/248286/theo-bendit) [at maths stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160982/how-is-x-1-x-2-normal-to-x-1w-1-x-2w-2-y/3160988#3160988)

> If you choose two points $(w_1, w_2), (v_1, v_2)$ along this line, then
>   $$(x_1, x_2) \cdot ((w_1, w_2) - (v_1, v_2)) = x_1 w_1 + x_2 w_2 - (x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2) = y - y = 0.$$
>   That is, the direction $(x_1, x_2)$ is perpendicular to any vector lying along the line, i.e. $(x_1, x_2)$ is normal to the line.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\frac12(x_1w_1 + x_2w_2 - y)^2$ is called the $Error (E)$ (assuming $y$ to be continuous which is not the case in case of classifiers). If you write this equation in Physics or Maths it represents a family of curves in 4D (the curves are continuous but for visualisation we will assume it to be a family of curves).

Here is a representative equation of what it would have looked like had the error been $\frac12(x_1w_1 - y)^2$ a 3D curve.

[image]

This is a scalar quantity which represents the value of error at different places for different values of $w1$ and $w2$. Now gradient of a scalar is defined as $\nabla F$, where $F$ is a scalar, on doing this operation you get a vector, which is perpendicular to the **equi-potential** or more suitably **equi-error** surface, i.e. if you trace all the points which give the same error, you will get a curve, and its gradient at any point is the vector perpendicular to the curve at that given point. There are many proofs for this but here is a very simple and nice [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599488/why-gradient-vector-is-perpendicular-to-the-plane).

Now lets look at the equation of the constraint $x_1w_1 + x_2w_2 = y$. In case of a 3D error curve, the constraint is giving us a **plane** which is **parallel** to the **tangential plane** of the **equi-error** surface at a given point. You can look at this [method](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32A/chap12/section4/793d3/793_3.html) of how to find tangential planes and derive the plane yourself, where $z = Error(E)$ and $w1$ and $y$ are your $x$ and $y$.

Thus it is quite clear that the gradient will be perpendicular to the constraint, and this is the reason we use gradients because according to mathematics if you move in a direction perpendicular to an equi-potential surface you get the maximum change than any other direction for same $dl$ movement.

I would highly suggest you check out these [videos](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/gradient-and-directional-derivatives/v/gradient) on gradient from Khan academy. This will hopefully give you a more intuitive understanding of why we do what we do in Neural Networks.